# How does the Church of East view the Passion of Christ?

Tags: christology, atonement, passion-of-jesus, nestorianism, assyrian-church-of-the-east

What is the understanding of the (Assyrian or Ancient) Church of the East on the Passion, considering their unique Christological doctrine?

Do they believe that God suffered on the cross?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).